# How to trigger an apex:actionFuction from an apex:commandButton without a page refresh?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, button, commandbutton

How can I add an `apex:commandButton` to a page doing the following:

- Executing an `apex:actionFunction`
- ReRendering some parts of the page (with `reRender=""`)
- **NOT** redirect to another page / refresh actual page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<apex:commandButton value="Do something" onclick="actionFunction(); return false;" />
<apex:actionFunction name="actionFunction" action="{!action}" rerender="someArea" />
```