# Load data without a page refresh

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery, refresh, outputpanel

I have a similar question to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/how-to-trigger-an-apexactionfuction-from-an-apexcommandbutton-without-a-page-r). But unfortunatly this solve does not work for me.

I am using a `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showCreditPull();" rerender="refreshOutputPannel" role="button"/>` for my button rather then a apex:commandButton.

The issue I am running into is: every time I run `showCreditPull()` the page reloads. Which I do not want to happen. My end goal is to press a button, load a spinner while the web callouts happen, then replace the spinner with the newly populated data.

`showCreditPull()` is my JavaScript function. This function calls my apex method `pullReport()`. This apex method brings back the data I want displayed on the page.

I believe my issue is with this apex method. When I remove the apex method from my function, I am able to update the page without a refresh. But I need this method so I am able to do a web callout and return data to the page.

Am I missing something with actionFunctions? Or Apex methods and javascript? I need to return the data to the server side without a page refresh.

I attempted to reRender a specific block on the page rather then the whole page but no success.

JS:

```
function showCreditPull() {
    pullReportOP(); //APEX method
    var panel = $('#divforspinner');
    var panel_body = panel.find('#oldPullreportbutton');
    var spinner = panel_body.find(".business-loading-icon"); //spinner
    if('{!bvs.Status__c}' != 'Completed') {
      $('.replaceDiv').replaceWith(spinner.show());
    }
    else if ('{!bvs.Status__c}' == 'Completed') {
      $('#oldPullreportbutton').replaceWith('#populatedChart');
    }
    else {
      spinner.hide();
    }
}
```

I have also attempted a while loop for this but it would get stuck in an infinite loop. I believe this is the correct way to call the spinner once I can figure out the page refresh.

```
//once data is loaded, stop the spinner.
while ('{!bvs.Status__c}' != 'Completed') {
    $('.replaceDiv').replaceWith(spinner.show());
    //break;
}
```

APEX:

```
public void pullReport()
{   
    serializeData(); //this is the POST and GET callout method
    bvs = new Business_Verification_Summary__c();//creating a new object
    insert bvs;
    bvs.Lexis_Nexis_Report_Link__c = jsonStr; //this data is pulled from serializeData()
    bvs.CreditReview__c = actId;
    bvs.Transaction_Date__c = newdate;//this data is pulled from serializeData()
    if (bvs.Transaction_Date__c != null)
    {
      bvs.Status__c = 'Completed';  
    } 
    update bvs;
}
```

VFP:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="refreshOutPutPannel">
    <div class="panel-body panel-footer">
        <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;text-align:center">
            <div class="disabledByZ-index"></div> 
                <input type="hidden" value="1" class="pullBizCredit"/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showCreditPull();" rerender="refreshOutPutPannel" role="button" class="btn permissionDeny btn-default">Pull Report2</a> 
        </div>
    </div> 

<div class="rowOP borderTop">       
    <div class="cellOP evenOP paddingStyle">        
        <div class="cellOP floatLOP paddingStyle">      
            Report Date     
        </div>      
        <div class="cellOP floatROP paddingStyle">      
            {!bvs.Transaction_Date__c}      
        </div>      
    </div>      
</div>      
<div class="rowOP">     
    <div class="cellOP oddOP paddingStyle">     
        <div class="cellOP floatLOP paddingStyle">      
            Full Report     
        </div>      
        <div class="cellOP floatROP paddingStyle">      
            <a href="{!bvs.Lexis_Nexis_Report_Link__c}" target="_blank" class="paddingStyle">View Details </a>      
        </div>      
    </div>      
</div>      
</apex:outputPanel>
```

CODE UPDATES:

```
  <apex:actionStatus id="spinnerStatus">
      <apex:facet name="start">
          <apex:outputPanel>
              <div class="business-loading-icon panel-body" align="center" style="display:none;margin-right:5px;height:178px;">
                  <span style='display: inline-block;height: 100%;vertical-align: middle;'></span>
                  <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.loadingspinner)}" style="height:100px" />
              </div>
          </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:facet>
  </apex:actionStatus>

<apex:commandLink action="{!pullReport}" reRender="refreshOutPutPannel" status="spinnerStatus" html-role="button" styleClass="btn permissionDeny btn-default" value="Pull Report" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pullReportOP` appears to be an [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm). You need to specify the `reRender` attribute on this element, *not* on your `a` anchor. Despite the JavaScript-y nature of apex:actionFunction, if you don't specify a reRender attribute on it, it will cause a page refresh.

Also, you don't need the JS you're using at all, you can simply use an [apex:actionStatus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm), like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="pullReportOP"
                     action="{!pullReport}"
                     reRender="refreshOutPutPannel"
                     status="spinnerStatus" />
<apex:actionStatus id="spinnerStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <!-- put spinner code here -->
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Alternatively, just use [apex:commandLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) instead of your normal link:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!pullReport}"
                  status="spinnerStatus"
                  reRender="refreshOutPutPannel"
                  html-role="button"
                  styleClass="btn permissionDeny btn-default"
                  value="Pull Report2" />
```

Comment: oh interesting. Thank you @sfdcfox. I am now able to return the data without a page refresh. The actionStatus is not working for the spinner but I will keep hacking away at that.

Comment: @Olivia If I remember correctly, if you want multiple elements in the facet, you have to wrap them inside an `apex:outputPanel`. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I've done some research and it looks like apex:actionStatus is the right way to go about it and I don't necessarily need to wrap it in apex:outputPanel.  I have attached the code updates with the actionStatus and the updated commandLink. I am not seeing anything wrong with this in comparison to other examples. Still not getting any response.Any insight? I am still digging as well...
Examples: *http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65580/popup-spinner-style-apexactionstatus* , *https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm*

Comment: @Olivia - the spinner is not displaying because the containing div style in your posted code is set to `display:none`

Comment: @Olivia Yeah, I just saw your code update, too. The actionStatus element specifically does the showing and hiding for you, so don't include any of your own hide/show CSS/JavaScript methods.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you, you were right with the display. But the more I dig into this, the more I think I do actually need JS. The actionStatus works but the div remains once the spinner is done. I need to hide it's div or replace the div with with the populated data. I am unable to replace the div unless I have JS. Unless I am missing something with actionStatus? I have tried `onStop`, eventlisteners, etc. I am thinking that because the DOM is already loaded and the page doesn't refresh, JS is not loading a 2nd time to hide the div. This leads me to believe that I need both JS and actionStatus.

Comment: but this is more like a second tier question, I can ask the community in a different thread! thank you for the original solve to the refresh.

Comment: If anyone reads this far down....onStop with actionStatus works. It just wasn't saving properly.